# Chrome trouble on SVG background image rendering

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, svg

The problem started on the last Chrome update, since then the images crop and just do not render properly, but not all of them, just a couple. 
I am using them this way:

```
.ch-info > div {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;  
  height: 105%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s linear;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}
```

Inside the `div` I have this class which provide the background image.

```
.img-1 { 
  background-image: url(../images/icons/name.svg);
  background-size:cover;
}
```

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

I have no idea how to fix it. I have seen that applying fixed sizes on the image solves it but the same size do not work for all the pics and I would wanna know what can be the problem. I was thinking that may be something related to changes on how the CSS property works since update but it's just a theory.

This happens only on Chrome.

Comment: Until you provide a [mcve] of your problem, where we could actually experience the bug and experiment possible solutions, your chances of getting help are quite low.

Comment: thank you, i added the class used as parent

Comment: That doesn't help. The code you posted so far is definitely "minimal" but it's hardly "complete" or "verifiable". In fact, it's hardly "an example". You should consider reproducing the bug in a snippet.

Comment: By the way, that "parent" is a complete mess. The only thing that is clear from it is that someone was desperately trying to center something both horizontally and vertically without understanding the principles. A lot of that code is useless and part of it is plain wrong. For example, there is absolutely no point in centering an element horizontally when it has a set width of 100%.

Comment: Have you had a bad day @AndreiGheorghiu?  Perhaps you would like to reconsider the tone of your comments?

Comment: Not at all, Paul. I believe pointing out flaws in code is one of the key concepts of this community and is genuinely helpful. Now you made me quite curious about how you would have formulated my comment above.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't intend it, but your comments here sound rude to me. Using the negative phrases "complete mess", "desperate" and "useless" likely will have intimidated a person who may be just a beginner.

Comment: @Fabiman89 If you are still having problems, please do as Andrei suggested and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see your code in action.

Comment: thank you, i will make a sniplet and edit as soon as posible.

Comment: I have the same issue. I found that the original svg has not right width into css info. I remove vieport and add into svg file width and height. It help, but when I zoom page, my icons not zoom, they still has properties as before. If anybody can help, it would be awesome!